# Use i18next translation hook for error messages

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-i18next

So I have a form which works fine and for error messages I have created a schema file which contains errors defined like this

```
export const dataInputCreateSchema = yupObject({
    company: yup.object().required('This field is required').nullable
  })
```

In my component I am initializing my i18next translation variable like this `const { t } = useTranslation('common')`. As to show the error messages in case if user touch the textbox and does not write anything then required field error will be shown and its working like this

`const companyFieldError = _.get(errors,'company', '');`

_.get is a lodash method that takes in an object, path and default value.

I need to know how I can pass my translation defined in common.json file to companyFieldError? Translation in common.json is something like

```
"errorMessages": { 
     "requiredField": "This is required Field"
  }
```

I don't want to discard my schema file but I want to provide key there and that key must get translated. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some changes I will make to support translation of errors.

1. Use the message in the schema definition.

```js
export const dataInputCreateSchema = yupObject({
    company: yup.object().required('errorMessages.requiredField').nullable
  })
```

2. Use the message to get the translated text.

```js
const message = _.get(errors,'company', '');
const companyFieldError = t(message);
```